# Apart from "berlinern", do any other German dialects have a corresponding verb?

Tags: verb, dialect

Das Verb [berlinern](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/berlinern) heißt:

> Deutsch mit berlinischem Akzent oder in Berliner Dialekt sprechen

Gibt es andere Dialekte, wobei es in Standardhochdeutsch einen Verb gibt, das bedeutet, diesen Dialekt zu sprechen?  Oder gibt es das nur bei *berlinern*?

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass *berlinern* Hochdeutsch ist, viel eher Umgangssprache. Falls der Begriff aus einer Berliner Mundart stammt, wäre die Bildungsform kaum von Hochdeutsch zu unterscheiden, der Unterschied ist relativ gering. Falls das zu schnell ging, nochmal langsam zum Mitlesen: Berlinerisch wird als Mundart bezeichnet und ist in gewissem Sinne gar kein Dialekt. Die Abgrenzung ist aber schwierig, und sollte daher vielleicht vermieden werden. Sonst führt es zu Problemen wie unten bei *bellen*. Vielleicht wurde eigentlich nur nach einer Bildungsform <Region>+<Suffixe> gefragt?

Comment: Eventuell macht einen Dialekt eben aus, dass gerade kein Einfluss auf die Standardsprache davon ausgeht. Das wären zumindest die klaren Fälle.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Das gibt es auch bei anderen Dialekten:

> Der Schwabe schwäbelt.
>   Der Sachse sächselt.

Comment: "Schwäbeln" habe ich noch nie gehört, "sächseln" allerdings schon

Comment: Wieder was gelernt ;-) - steht auch in [Wikitionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schw%C3%A4beln). Google liefert über 19.000 Treffer.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf   Ha no! Ha wa! I scho! Aber natürlich sagen Schwaben nicht schwäbeln, schwäbeln sagen nur Nichtschwaben.-  Jedoch, Achtung! *Berlinern* bedeutet: Berliner Dialekt sprechen, während *schwäbeln* bedeutet: Hochdeutsch mit schwäbischem Akzent sprechen. Schwäbisch sprechen ist nicht schwäbeln!

Comment: ... und die Norddeutschen _plätten_ ;) Aber mal ernsthaft: mir fallen nicht wirklich weitere Dialekte ein, für die es eigene Verben gibt. Ist die Liste mit _berlinern, schwäbeln, sächseln_ vielleicht schon komplett?

Comment: ... und der Friese [frieselt](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/frieseln), Baden(s)er baden. Kölner kellnern,... ;)

Comment: *plätten* und *frieseln* finde ich unter diese Bedeutung nicht ins Wörturbuch, ist das Umgangssprache/Dialekt/falsch/ein Witz?

Comment: @gerrit: frieseln ist im Duden ([plätten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/plaetten) übrigens auch). Der Link war schon in der Ursprungsversion (ohne Badener und Kölner) vorhanden. Aber ja, ganz ernst war es nicht.

Comment: @gerrit plätten und frieseln waren Witze

Comment: Der Hesse "hesselt" auch

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt Jo, aber nicht in die Bedeutung von "Friesisch sprechen" oder "Platt sprechen".

Comment: Die Franken fränkeln und die Kranken kränkeln.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann i hao oofd scho so ebes gheert wia "do schwäbelschd aber ebes zsamma"

Comment: @Sentry: "hesseln" kenne ich nicht und habe ich - außer als Ortsname - auch nicht gefunden. Aber "[nassauern](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/nassauern-nassauern/8755022.html)" kann ich noch ergänzen. Das Verb bezieht sich sogar auf die Einwohner Nassaus, hat aber auch nichts mit dem dortigen Dialekt zu tun.

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt Im Duden steht das auch nicht, damit ist wohl die Vorgabe des OP (Standardhochdeutsch) nicht ganz erfüllt. Google hat zumindest einen Forenbeitrag geliefert und ich kenne es aus dem Sprachgebrauch. (Ich lebe im Schwabenland und wenn ich mit meinen Eltern telefoniere, sagt meine Freundin oft "Du hesselst wieder")

Comment: @Sentry: Dann ist das sogar eine ernsthafte Antwort, wenn sich eine gewisse Verbreitung belegen lässt.

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt Habe gerade sogar [eine Buchquelle](https://books.google.de/books?id=mszNAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT183&lpg=PT183&dq=%22%22du+hesselst%22&source=bl&ots=6CTqVsoksq&sig=ACfU3U1ONkJ3lfnoieOAwzZmzrhb_mh2pg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXzIOIhqfhAhUCZVAKHYE1A68Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ) gefunden

Comment: @Sentry: Dann füge doch eine Antwort hinzu! Es ist ja nicht so, dass es bereits dutzende besserer Antworten gibt.

Answer (score 3):

> hamburgern

bedeutet laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hamburgern):

> Hamburger Mundart sprechen

Obwohl ich seit mehreren Jahren in Hamburg wohne, habe ich das Wort noch nie bewusst wahrgenommen.

*Ergänzung:*

Beim Lesen der Kommentare wird eine besondere Schwierigkeit deutlich: Es ist nicht offensichtlich, was überhaupt Hamburgisch ist. Es gibt nämlich [drei Hamburger Dialekte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_Dialekt) (sofern man diese nicht weiter unterteilt):

1. Plattdeutsch, wie es noch immer in Hamburg gesprochen wird (ca. [100.000 Sprecher](https://www.hamburg.de/stadtleben/4108598/plattdeutsch-geschichte/)).
2. Hamburger Missingsch: Eine Mischform zwischen Platt und Hochdeutsch.
3. Hochdeutsch mit einigen lokalen Besonderheiten.

Comment: Im Stadtkern von Hamburg geboren und aufgewachsen, jetzt über 30 Jahre hier. Nie gehört.

Comment: Ich hatte in Kindertagen einen Freund, bei dem hieß "Ich will hamburgern", dass er jetzt gerne einen Burger verdrücken würde.

Comment: Ne, natürlich nicht, denn es heißt "Platt snaken". Sicherlich wird das auch zu "snacken".gekürzt (sicher bin ich mir aber nicht, daher nur Kommentar). Eigentlich heißt es nur "sprechen, schwatzen". So oder so: da es als feste Wendung besteht, kann die Verbalphrase als Verb gezählt werden. Platt ist aber nicht exklusiv Hamburg, und Hamburg nicht exklusiv Plattdeutsch.

Comment: @vectory in Hamburg insbesondere »Missingsch«

Answer (score 3):

Aus dem eigenen Sprachgebrauch und meinem Umfeld kenne ich noch

> hesseln

Mein Heimatdialekt ist [Mittelhessisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittelhessische_Dialekte) und ich lebe seit zehn Jahren im Schwabenland. Nach Telefonaten mit meinen Eltern oder Freunden aus der Heimat sagt mir meine Freundin oft:

> Du hesselst wieder.

Es steht zwar nicht im Duden, aber ich konnte zumindest zwei Quellen im Internet finden (Hervorhebung durch mich):

> »Ich kann nicht genau sagen, woher der Dialekt in deiner Stimme kommt. Wo hast du denn vorher gelebt?«
>
> »In Frankfurt.«
>
> »Genau, das ist es, **du hesselst ein bisschen**.«

Quelle: [Acht Zimmer, Küche, Meer: Roman
von Anna Rosendahl](https://books.google.de/books?id=mszNAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT183&lpg=PT183&dq=%22du%20hesselst%22&source=bl&ots=6CTqVsultu&sig=ACfU3U3rml0ODw1Cppife4iIYJVZ2qpKOA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVwbTrnKfhAhVBy6QKHUDvBVwQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22du%20hesselst%22&f=false)

Und hier aus einem [FAZ-Artikel](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/rhein-main/kultur/theaterfestival-verhaach-die-kist-11114182.html):

> **Sie hesseln alle**, mal mehr, [...], mal weniger, [...].

Answer (score 2):

Nicht unbedingt ein deutscher Dialekt, aber ein Dialekt des Deutschen: Steirer *bellen*.

Comment: Hallo WolfgangGroiss, willkommen auf German SE. Die Frage wäre hier allerdings, ob Steirer auch steiern, und da sie das (vermutlich) nicht tun, geht diese Antwort ein wenig an der Frage vorbei. Es sei denn, man bezeichnet die Steiermark auch als Bellerland und die Steirer als Beller, dann wäre die Antwort gut ;)

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage so, dass es *ein Verb* geben muss - die Anforderung, dass das die Verbform des Ortsnamens sein muss, lese ich da nicht, auch wenn das für das Beispiel natürlich zutrifft.

Comment: Stimmt, aber _berlinern_ heißt nur "Berlinerisch reden", _bellen_ heißt nicht nur "Steirisch reden"

Comment: @sgf, wenn einer von Außerhalb *bellen* sagen solte, was zumindest im Umkreis denkbar wäre, dann bezeichnet es sicherlich das Dialektreden. Gemeindeutsch ist der Begriff damit noch nicht, was eventuell nur eine Bildungslücke darstellt, die hier geschlossen werden soll. Kommt also ganz drauf an.

Comment: @vectory, Ich hab auch schon Hunde bellen gehört...

Comment: @vectory Dazu kommt, dass *bellen* natürlich auch eine nicht mit Irgendeiner Sprachvarietät verbundene Art zu sprechen bezeichnet (»Er bellte einen Befehl«), woran man vermutlich zuerst denkt, wenn man das Wort in bezug auf das Sprechen hört.